# Widget shows blank page

Tags: php, android-studio

I have serious problem with my widget because after successful start icon shows and then blank page appears. Also terminal shows some errors:

- *E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1
- E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(335)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS*

My code looks like this:

MainActivity

```
 package com.example.foodreview;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mywebView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings=mywebView.getSettings();
        mywebView.loadUrl("http://foodreview.com.pl/");
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }

    public static class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed () {
        if (mywebView.canGoBack()) {
            mywebView.goBack();
        } else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.foodreview">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".splashactivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I do not have any idea what goes wrong.